# SQLFeatureNotSupportedException on Amazon Redshift

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run some ETL process on Amazon Redshift. It's written in Apache Spark. Same code works fine on Postgres but with Redshift is throwing `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver not capable.` error.

I am trying to read data from flat files and write it to the tables. Spark code look like this

```
spark
     .read.schema(getFileNameAndSchema(table)._2).csv(getFileNameAndSchema(table)._1)
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .jdbc("jdbc:redshift://url:5429", table, dbProperties())
```

While googling for it I found that this type is thrown if `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` cursors are not supported by the database. If this is the case the with RedShift then what is the work around?

Comment: That's because Redshift is a forked version of Postgres 8.X and I believe your code works with Postgres 9.X ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. If this is the case, how can I resolve it?

Comment: I'm not much familiar with those cursors from Postgres. Would you care elaborating on what you are trying to do maybe someone else can also help ?

Comment: Updated with spark code.

Comment: Try googling about `Amazon S3 bucket` and `Copy command` to load data from **CSV file** to **Amazon Redshift**.