# Does resultset returned by redshift supports resetting iterator?

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

As the title, it seems that resultset returned by Redshift JDBC does not support ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE or ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are discussing same issue here [SQLFeatureNotSupportedException on Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40496316/sqlfeaturenotsupportedexception-on-amazon-redshift) (eg. it's not supported because Redshift is too old fork of Postgres where they could do this only since v. 9.X).

You can try Postgres JDBC driver, but I don't think it will work either.
(IMHO)